# how to add Button to android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on an android chat app and I want to add a Send button to android keyboard . and also i want my entry message edit text show's up the android keyboard.(Like Nimbuzz chat app).
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is possible. The soft keyboard is itself an application and you can't change it unless you decompile it.

However, you can try a horizontal linear layout carrying an edittext widget and a customized send button.

I have seen that on search widget the button on key board changes to search. I believe it has something to do with searchable activity.